# How to send Content-Disposition headers in apache for files?

Tags: apache-2.2, http, http-headers

I have a directory of text files that I'm serving out with apache 2. Normally when I (or any user) access the files they see them in their browser. I want to 'force'* the web browser to pop up a 'Save as' dialog box. I know this is possible to do with the `Content-Disposition` headers ([more info](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260519)).

Is there some way to turn that on for each file?

Ideally I'd like something like this:

```
<Directory textfiles>
   AutoAddContentDispositionHeaders On
</Directory>
```

And then apache would set the correct content disposition header, including using the same filename.

Something like this might be possible with the apache `Header` directive.

Bonus points if it's included by standing in apache in debian.

I could do a simple PHP wrapper script that takes in a `filename` argument, makes the call to `header(...)` and then prints the file, but then i have to validdate input etc. that's work I'm trying to avoid.

---

* I know you can't actually force things when it comes to the web

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have discovered that this does what I want:

```
<Location /textfiles>
    SetEnvIf Request_URI "^.*/([^/]*)$" FILENAME=$1
    Header set "Content-disposition" "attachment; filename=%{FILENAME}e"
    UnsetEnv FILENAME
</Location>
```

Comment: What is the "e" for at the end of the file name? I see that it doesn't work without it, but I don't understand what it does.

Comment: It just means "the contents of the environment variable named `FILENAME`" (see documentation of mod_headers: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html)

Answer (score 2):

`mod_headers` should be what you are looking for:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c> 
  <Location ~ ".*/textfiles/.*"> 
    Header set Content-Disposition attachment
  </Location>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: A good start, but i also want the filename in there so that it pops up the (same) filename. However I have found a similar solution