# Error 'Content-Disposition:' contains invalid characters when downloading xlsx file apache

Tags: apache-2.4

It works for other extension pdf,doc,png, but only for xlsx apache throws below error in error log:

'Content-Disposition:' contains invalid characters

Could you please help me fix this issue?

Comment: maybe related: https://serverfault.com/questions/101948/how-to-send-content-disposition-headers-in-apache-for-files

Comment: Show the exact error and your configuration.